# How to solve "Error: 'describe' is not defined" in Nextjs with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, next.js

I'm trying to build my Nextjs project for production, but I have next errors:

```bash
./components/Layout/Header/Header.test.tsx
6:1  Error: 'describe' is not defined.  no-undef
7:20  Error: 'jest' is not defined.  no-undef
9:3  Error: 'it' is not defined.  no-undef
11:5  Error: 'expect' is not defined.  no-undef
14:3  Error: 'it' is not defined.  no-undef
19:5  Error: 'expect' is not defined.  no-undef
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it in eslint file:

```
{
...
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true, // << Add this line
  },
...
}
```